# How to tell whether the given file was saved by `saveRDS` or by `save` without loading it?

Tags: r

I work in an environment, where we heavily depend on Excel to do the statistical job. We have our own Excel workbooks that create reports, charts and compute the models. But sometimes the Excel is not enough, so we would like to use R to augment the data processing.

I am developing a fairly universal and low-level Excel workbook that is capable to convert our data structures stored in Excel workbook into R [using rcom and RExcel macros](http://rcom.univie.ac.at/download.html#RExcel). Because data are large, the process of porting them into R is lengthy (in terms of the time a used needs to wait after pressing F9 to recalculate the workbook), so I started to develop caching capabilities to my Excel workbook.

Caching is achieved by embedding an extra attribute to the saved object(s), that is a function that checks if the `mtime` of the Excel's workbook with the data structure did not change since the time the R object was created. Additionally the template supports saving the objects into disk, so next time it is not mandatory to use the workbook and the original Excel data structures in the first place, when doing calculations that involve mostly R.

Although for the most cases the user wouldn't care, but internally sometimes it is more natural to save the data into one R object (like `data.frame`), and sometimes it seems that saving a whole set o multiple R objects is more intuitive.

When saving a single R object, the `saveRDS` is more convenient, so I prefer it over `save`, which works only for multiple objects. (I know, that I can always render multiple objects into one by combining them in the list)

According to the manual for `saveRDS` the file generated by `save` has first 5 bytes equal to ASCII representation of `RDXs\n`. Is there any ready function to test that, or should I manually open the file asbinary, read the 5 bytes, trap a corner case if the file doesn't have even 5 bytes, close the file, etc.?

Comment: The examples for both functions use different file extensions:  `.RData` and `.rds`. In my opinion, that's what you and your users should stick to.

Comment: True, but what if they don't?

Comment: Can you give more specifics? Who are your users (teammates, clients, management)? Can you provide them the function(s) for saving their data? Or constrain them to one type of file? Who's doing the post-analysis? If it is the user, can he/she read and understand an error message?

Comment: Adam, unless your users are pains-in-the-youknow (like me) who do things like changing the extensions on Excel files to `.txt` or `.pptx` , this should not be a concern.  But if you must :-),  how about `system('head(yourfile')` or other system calls which provide file info.

Comment: @flodel Here you are.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Although my users *will* occasionally give file names to save the R objects, they wouldn't really need to know, that the R is involved at all. All they see is a smart Excel workbook.

Comment: ??????? If all they are using is Excel, how can they be naming `R` files?  Please explain what's going on here.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Each excel data structure has a field that defines the full path to its R counterpart.

Comment: To use the vernacular:  **ur doin it rong**  . Write your code so the user enters at most the "base" filename and the underlying code appends the desired extension, path, etc.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - Thank you, that is exactly, what I am doing right now.

Comment: I agree with Carl. I'll add that if it was my application, I would only use one format: RDS. And use lists like you already mentioned.